# Is this change of speech correct?

Tags: reported-speech

> *She said, "I'd like to see it again."*

I changed its speech into:

> *She said she wanted to see it again.*

Is this a correct change in speech?

Why or why not?

Comment: You can also keep the conditional: *She said she would like to see it again.*

Answer (score 1):

Would like = want

I would like to see it again = I want to see it again.

> Direct narration : She said, "I'd like to see it again."
>
> Indirect narration : She said (that) she would like to see it again.
>
> Or,
>
> She said (that) she wanted to see it again.